# Event object from Lamda function is changing during code execution

Tags: node.js, lambda, api-gateway

I've created a Lambda function integrated with AWS API Gateway.
I've configured a template model from the Integration Request so that i can access request headers from the Event object in Lambda function.

[Integration Request Configuration :](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AFvOX.png)

From cloudWatch i observe that the console.log(event) is not always empty during code execution :

[CloudWatch logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5j4nT.png)

The below code generated the CloudWatch logs :

```
var moment = require('moment');

var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var keyPairId = 'APKAIPZ5BRDMEXAMPLE';

var privateKey = '';

var signer = new AWS.CloudFront.Signer(keyPairId, privateKey);
var expireTime = moment().add(3600, 'sec').unix();

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {

   console.log(event.headers); //logged twice from cloudWatch

   console.log(event.headers); //Undefined although i can see the data from cloudwatch...

   var domain = 'mydomain.com';
   var resource = 'https://cdn.mydomain.com/*';
   var attributes = '; domain=' + domain + '; path=/; secure; httpOnly'

   var options = {policy : '{"Statement":[{"Resource":"' + resource + 
   '","Condition":{"DateLessThan":{"AWS:EpochTime":' + expireTime + 
    '}}}]}'};

    signer.getSignedCookie(options, function(err, data) {

        if (err) {
        //do somehing

        } else {

           context.done(null, {

            'Set-Cookie': 'CloudFront-Policy=' + data["CloudFront-Policy"] + attributes,
            'SEt-Cookie': 'CloudFront-Signature=' + data["CloudFront-Signature"] + attributes,
            'SeT-Cookie': 'CloudFront-Key-Pair-Id=' + data["CloudFront-Key-Pair-Id"] + attributes


       });

    }
});
};
```

As stated in the code above, could you please explain why        `console.log(event)` is logged twice from cloudWatch and `console.log(event['headers'])` causes an exception as headers is undefined although i can see the data from cloudwatch ?

Thanks a lot!

**EDIT :**

The lambda function is called using REST(CORS). I've logged two HTTP requests from my browser :

HTTP Request with method : OPTIONS

```
OPTIONS https://mycdn-domain.net/authenticate
Access-Control-Request-Method: GET
Origin: https://origin-domain.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.157 Safari/537.36
Access-Control-Request-Headers: x-api-key
Accept: */*
```

HTTP Request with method : GET

```
GET https://mycdn-domain.net/authenticate
Origin: https://origin-domain.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.157 Safari/537.36
x-api-key: ************************************
Accept: */*
```

Comment: Could you also inscribe the sample request that was used to trigger the lambda function?

Comment: yes, i've edited the question with http requests logs.